# How to deploy app with Nginx, React, Webpack, Gunicorn, PostgreSQL, Django & DRF on AWS Elastic Beanstalk? How to handle static files with this app?

Tags: django, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS environment. I've few questions regarding AWS deployment. An important point to remember here is that I am using **free tier of AWS**. So I've limitations about resources.

**Question1:**
I've developed a web app on my local server (using VM with centos Linux) which uses *React-SSR* for the frontend using *Express* server. React CSR and SSR is generated using *webpack*. Backend uses *Django* as main framework, *postgreSQL* for database. Frontend and backend communicate with the help of Django Rest Framework. *Gunicorn* is used to run backend server. I want to use *Nginx* as reverse proxy server. How can I deploy this app on *AWS Elastic Beanstalk*? Can *Amazon S3* be used to run React-SSR frontend?

**Question 2:**
This app serves images which'll be uploaded through backend. What's the proper way to handle images and static files with this kind of app? Should images be handled by nginx, react or django? How should I configure Django so that it stores image paths properly in its model(ImageField is used)? Where does Amazon S3 fit in this?

**Question 3:** 
Can this app be made region agnostic under free tier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer to the first question**: React can be deployed on AWS S3, if you configure webpack for generate static files (HTML + CSS + JS), or use the [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/) for generate static on build.

**The answer to the second question**: To use AWS S3 for storing statiс use [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html)